# Does django logs user in when register without authenticate() and login() function?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-registration, django-sessions

I am practicing django user registration using `UserCreationForm()` and `User()` class.

My froms.py code is.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class user(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

My views.py code for this is.

```
def register(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.user(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=False)
        form.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        form.save()
        #context = {'form':form, 'er':form.errors}
        return redirect('register')
else:
    form = forms.user()
    context = {'form':form, 'er':form.errors}
    return render(request, 'register/register.html', context)
```

I did not use `authenticate()` or `login()` in the registration system.

I have three questions. **In case of using same browser.

1. When I register does the user automatically log in and create a session number or does not?
2. If does log in and generate a session value, what happens if registers again with a new value from same browser? Does system delete previous session and generate new session or something else happens.
3. If I have used `authenticate()` and `login()`, what would happen if I try to register again?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `form.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just wanted to clean the email data so no error occurs. As far I know this is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

- It depends on your implementation. As long as you only save a user the user is only written to your DB.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in
- If you successfully created a user, you can't create a user with the same username again as the username is a unique identifier in the Django User Model.

To see if something is written to your session you can look into your DB.
Besides you might consider using an [activation mail](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef).

Comment: Sorry. Lately I was not being able to connect to internet. OK, I got one thing, it does not log the user in after registration automatically. But What would happen if a user is logged in and someone else is trying to register on the same browser? "TIA"

Comment: again a new entry in the DB but nothing else.. unless you change the default implementation

Comment: OK. What if registration and login is implemented at the same time?(In case of "after registration the user gets logged in automatically") Would that log the previous user out and the new user in when new registration occurs?

Comment: That depends on how you implement the registration view